# How to write a technical requirement covering both singular and plural

Tags: parenthetical-plural

I have a requirement:

> The system shall store errors.

I want the requirement to be true if there are one or more errors.
Is this the case for the above, in regards to grammar/english language and writing rules etc?

(This is a very high level requirement and it is only an example, so please don't dissect it too much)

I could write

> The system shall store one or more errors.

but my question remains, if the first example is valid or if I shall change all requirements to state the "one or more" line as well in order to be grammatically correct.

Thanks

Comment: Funny! You added the tag "parenthetical-plural" but overlooked the answer to your question that it contained right there. Really?

Comment: The verb *store* may or may not be accurate. If all you want is an error count, then *record* (or just *count*) would be more accurate. The use of *store* implies that it is dealing specifically with error *messages*.

Answer (score 3):

The system shall store **any** error(s).

For a brief explanation see the Tag on this question (Point the mouse at the Tag and hold).

Comment: Sorry, but the word "any" could be interpreted that the system shall store all possible errors, even those not needed to be stored. "Any" is a word which shall not commonly be used in requirement writing. Besides, just noticed you made it even vaguer by adding the (s) in the end. Please just answer the question, do not give alternative ways to reach the goal.

Comment: *Any* is perfectly accurate (it's what's meant by "one or more") and it certainly doesn't mean "all *possible*" since "possible" did not qualify it.

Comment: Sorry, @JasonBassford. "Any" should not be used since it could mean any errors unrelated to the aim of the system. As I said, this is a high level requirement, and at this level one dictates WHAT is needed. not HOW, that is further down the line. And by stating "Any" at this top level is wrong. AGAIN, you are simply not answering the question. Add some value!